# getting the sound and mic to work from google aiy kit on your own image

Tags: hardware

I bought and installed the Google AIY sound kit and am trying to get it to work with my own image.  i followed their hacking.md file and installed all the hardware drivers but "arecord -l" shows no capture hardware devices.  Hence arecord will not work

Has anyone had success in getting this kit to work without google Aiy image?  I know it works on their image but I was hoping to install in on a previously configured raspbian image.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you have not configured the correct dtoverlay in /boot/config.txt
It is named `googlevoicehat-soundcard.dtbo`